# Bootstrap Responsive Image Carousel Sizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to make a website for all devices. This website contains a row that is solely devoted to an image carousel. The code for this carousel is below.

```
<div class="row" id="imageCarouselRow">

    <div class="col-md-12" id="imageCarouselColumn">

        <div id="imageCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="Image link" class="img-responisve" alt="Caption">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Image Link" class="img-responsive" alt="Caption">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Image Link" class="img-responsive" alt="Caption">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Image Link" class="img-responsive" alt="Caption">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Image Link" class="img-responsive" alt="Caption">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see it contains 5 different images (the real links are included in the actual code) all of which I've given the 'img-responsive' class so the images can be scaled to different devices.

My problem is that the image carousel does not take up the entire row, but I still want it to be the only thing on the row. I also want it to be centralised. Additionally, on desktops since the carousel is the size of the entire row images will transition in from the very edge of the screen which I do not want, I only want the image to transition in from the edge of the previous image (i.e the carousel is no bigger than the size of the individual images)

Each individual image is 1025px by 424px by default.

The only way I have managed to accomplish this so far is by making the imageCarousel class have a size in px or em in an external stylesheet and give it a margin property of 0 auto that looks like this below:

```
#imageCarousel{
    width: 1025px;
    height: 424px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I've also set the size in em's. The problem is if I do this the size is static which stops bootstrap from scaling the site to different device sizes and when the browser window is rescaled.

Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use all classess for all media 
for Example col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 
and for image responsiveness use image responsive class image-responsive
Check this for more [Sample](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_img-responsive&stacked=h)

Comment: I have already used img-responsive for all my images and the image carousel is nested inside a col-md-12 div so this does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Using percentages instead of em's or px to define the size of the image carousel fixed the issue